# error with installing ruby via rvm on macbook air

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

Just got my first mac and I am trying to set up a ruby dev environment.  I have updated with XCode and Homebrew and RVM.   I am trying to get RVM to install Ruby 1.9.2 but it fails.

Any ideas?

```
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/mlanza/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/mlanza/.rvm/src
Error running 'tar xmzf /Users/mlanza/.rvm/archives/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz -C /Users/mlanza/.rvm/src ', please read /Users/mlanza/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/yaml/extract.log
Configuring yaml in /Users/mlanza/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running ' ./configure --prefix="/Users/mlanza/.rvm/usr"  ', please read /Users/mlanza/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /Users/mlanza/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/mlanza/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/yaml/make.log
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/mlanza/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #downloading ruby-1.9.2-p320, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #extracted to /Users/mlanza/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #configuring 
Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/mlanza/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/mlanza/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/mlanza/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

I am familiar with Ubuntu and didn't have issues there.  I was expecting Macs to be a bit easier.

Comment: Perhaps more suited to superuser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue after upgrading to Mountain Lion. If I remember correctly it's because the latest version of Xcode doesn't come bundled with the command line tools anymore.

You can still download them for free by visiting https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ and searching for Command Line Tools for Xcode 4.5 (OS X Mountain Lion). You'll need a free developer account to access the downloads area.

Comment: Thanks, Guys.  I was able to get around the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to read `rvm requirements` - it tells you how to install `gcc-4.2` which is required to successfully install Ruby on on osx, you can try with `clang` (which comes with latest xcode), but it can bring you random issues especially with Fibers.